# Problem with "No module named 'pygame'" while actually have it

Tags: python, error-handling, pygame

So I just came up with a problem that i don't understand.
I have two python files one is for the separate game menu, and second for the game.
The menu is written with tkinter and the problem comes when I click( in my menu ) 'Start game' button. It destroys menu, but does not open another file - game. Here's the code from menu where the problem occurs.

```
root.destroy()
os.system('main.py')
```

That's what console says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Initial code from the second file (game file)

```
from backdoor import *
import pygame
from Config import *
pygame.init()
```

When I start only the game file it works as it should - there's no Errors, that's why i have no idea why this problem occurs. I'm new to coding so would appreciate any help and explanations.

Comment: *"...while actually have it ..."* - No, you don't "have" it. Do you have different versions of Python installed? Try `pip3 install pygame`

Answer (score 0):

To import pygame you must have it installed:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

If you have it already installed try to reinstall

```
pip3 uninstall pygame
pip3 install pygame
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, so the problem was my sillnes and a lack of knowledge. I was using Anaconda environment and I've installed pygame with navigator cmd, so i thought that it's installed. I've reinstalled Python and added pip path in cmd with `setx PATH "%PATH%;path"`, then I could actually install pygame and now everything works properly. Thanks for help!